# CSS inline-block objects expanding on hover, elements lose their order while hovered

Tags: html, css

Im using HTML and CSS to make few inline-block boxes that expands on hover. But the problem is, while hovering on any block different than last one one of the boxes disappear, and while selecting first one in line something weird happens and one of them is moving to line above. I have tried diffrent things, but seems nothing helps. Here is CSS code:

```
.floating-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 125px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaa80;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.floating-box:hover {
    height:150px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width:120px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #e0e0d1;
    padding-right: 1px 
}
```

And JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lms6ve8/

Comment: I forgot to add, i want hovered boxes to stay in place and dont move the others, it has to partly cover other ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for you where they stay in place on `hover`.

This can be done with a pseudo element as well, though I used an extra `div` if you intend to have more content inside it.

```css
.floating-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 125px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.floating-box .box-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #aaaa80;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.floating-box:hover .box-wrapper {
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e0e0d1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-box">
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <span style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify;">sample text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="floating-box">
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <span style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify;">sample text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="floating-box">
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <span style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify;">sample text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="floating-box">
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <span style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify;">sample text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="floating-box">
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <span style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify;">sample text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="floating-box">
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <span style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify;">sample text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="floating-box">
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <span style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify;">sample text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="floating-box">
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <span style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify;">sample text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `position:absolute;` from your `.floating-box:hover` selector

`position:absolute;` takes the element "out" of the normal flow of element, and the reason you see the last element of your grid "disappearing" is that all elements after the hovered one goes back one place since the hovered one (positioned absolute) was just pulled out of the flow.

Comment: I forgot to add, i want hovered boxes to stay in place and dont move the others, it has to partly cover other ones

Comment: @login100100 updated the jsfiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lms6ve8/20/

Answer (score 0):

please remove `position`

```
.floating-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 125px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaa80;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.floating-box:hover {

    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width:120px;
     height:150px;
    background-color: #e0e0d1;
    padding-right: 1px
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/6Lms6ve8/19/)

Comment: I forgot to add, i want hovered boxes to stay in place and dont move the others, it has to partly cover other ones

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed your code in jsfiddle.

```
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.floating-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 125px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaa80;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom:4px;
}

.floating-box:hover {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width:120px;
    background-color: #e0e0d1;
    padding-right: 1px
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add, i want hovered boxes to stay in place and dont move the others, it has to partly cover other ones

Comment: that's because you adding a height to hover div

Answer (score 0):

Change your .floating-box:hover  position to relative

```css
.floating-box {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 125px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaa80;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.floating-box:hover {
    height:150px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width:120px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #e0e0d1;
    padding-right: 1px
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-box"> 
            <span style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify;">sample text here</span>
                </div>
        <div class="floating-box">
            <span style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify;">sample text here</span>
                </div>
        <div class="floating-box"> 
            <span style="font-size:12px; text-align:justify;">sample text here</span>
                </div>
        <div class="floating-box"> 
            <span style="font-size:12px; text-align:justify;">sample text here</span>
                </div>
        <div class="floating-box"> 
            <span style="font-size:12px; text-align:justify;">sample text here</span>
                </div>
        <div class="floating-box"> 
            <span style="font-size:12px; text-align:justify;">sample text here</span>
                </div>
        <div class="floating-box"> 
            <span style="font-size:12px; text-align:justify;">sample text here</span>
                </div>
        <div class="floating-box"> 
            <span style="font-size:12px; text-align:justify;">sample text here</span>
                </div>
```

Comment: please check my comment, enlarged box has to partly cover one below, without moving other boxes downward

Answer (score 0):

Removing `position:absolute;` and insert `transition: all .3s ease;` for animate

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/ujt5qcfv/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **position absolute** and add some transitions to make it presentable. Your adding **height** when you **hover** on **div** thats why the **elements** below are moving.
heres the fiddle:

```
position:absolute
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s7grcqws/